# WiFi driver not working in 20.04 LTS. When I try to install bcmwl-kernel-source it gives error

Tags: kernel, dpkg, broadcom, wifi-hardware-switch, wifi-direct

WiFi driver not working in 20.04 LTS. When I try to install bcmwl-kernel-source it gives error

```
eamon@eamon  ~  sudo apt-get --purge remove bcmwl-kernel-source
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bcmwl-kernel-source*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 250665 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-36-generic
 eamon@eamon  ~  sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bcmwl-kernel-source
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,544 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,068 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 bcmwl-kernel-source amd64 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5 [1,544 kB]
Fetched 1,544 kB in 3s (555 kB/s)                
Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
(Reading database ... 250665 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-36-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.8.0-36-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package bcmwl-kernel-source (--configure):
 installed bcmwl-kernel-source package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bcmwl-kernel-source
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start your pc in recovery mode and select dpkg and install broken packages. Then restart. It might solve error.